# How to do groupby max to create new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have dataframe like below to which I want apply an sql logic which mentioned below

```
df.head(25)

ORDER_ID    CODE    STATUS_DATE                       RNK
19837715    0400    22/10/19 08:11:08.000000000 AM GMT  2
19837715    0400    22/10/19 10:00:03.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837715    0400    22/10/19 10:47:08.000000000 AM GMT  3
19837715    0500    22/10/19 10:00:00.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837715    1100    01/11/19 10:02:00.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837715    1240    02/11/19 08:00:00.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837833    0400    22/10/19 08:13:09.000000000 AM GMT  3
19837833    0400    22/10/19 08:22:09.000000000 AM GMT  4
19837833    0400    23/10/19 04:30:10.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837833    0400    23/10/19 09:30:07.000000000 PM GMT  2
19837833    0500    23/10/19 01:08:00.000000000 AM GMT  1
19837833    0500    23/10/19 04:30:00.000000000 AM GMT  3
19840750    0500    23/10/19 12:30:00.000000000 PM GMT  1
19840750    1100    01/11/19 10:06:02.000000000 AM GMT  1
19840750    1240    02/11/19 08:40:05.000000000 AM GMT  1
19840750    1305    05/11/19 07:21:03.000000000 AM GMT  2
19840750    1305    05/11/19 08:22:03.000000000 AM GMT  1
19840750    1400    09/11/19 06:13:12.000000000 AM GMT  3
```

I want to apply the below sql logic on this dataframe.

```
select
    order_id
    , TRUNC(MAX(decode(df.code, '0400', STATUS_DATE, Null))) act_0400
    , TRUNC(MAX(decode(df.code, '0500', STATUS_DATE, Null))) act_0500
from
    dataframe df  
where 
      df.rnk =1 
group by    
    order_id
```

Here I am trying to create new columns act_0400 and act_0500  by taking maximum date value from the status date column for condition rank =1 and grouping them based on order id

**Expected Output**

```
ORDER_ID    ACT_0400    ACT_0500
19837715    22/10/2019  22/10/2019
19837833    23/10/2019  23/10/2019
19840750                23/10/2019
```

How could this be done in pandas

Comment: The logic is not completely clear. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Also,Can you post the expected output for the given dataframe as well?

Comment: @Moys, I have updated the expected Output. Here I am trying to create new columns `act_0400` and `act_0500` by taking maximum date value from the status date column for condition rank =1 and grouping them based on order id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert `STATUS_DATE` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate `max`, last some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['STATUS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['STATUS_DATE']).dt.date
df = (df[(df['RNK'] == 1) & df['CODE'].isin([400,500])]
        .pivot_table(index="ORDER_ID", columns="CODE", values="STATUS_DATE", aggfunc='max')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .add_prefix('ACT_')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   ORDER_ID     ACT_400     ACT_500
0  19837715  2019-10-22  2019-10-22
1  19837833  2019-10-23  2019-10-23
2  19840750         NaN  2019-10-23
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do:

```
codes = [400, 500]
df1 = (df
     .query("CODE in @codes and RNK == 1")
     .groupby(['ORDER_ID','CODE'])['STATUS_DATE']
     .first()
     .unstack())

# fix column names
df1.columns.name = None
df1 = df1.add_prefix('ACT_').reset_index()

   ORDER_ID     ACT_400     ACT_500
0  19837715  2019-10-22  2019-10-22
1  19837833  2019-10-23  2019-10-23
2  19840750         NaN  2019-10-23
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below

```
a = df.loc[df['RNK']==1 & (df['CODE']==400) | (df['CODE']==500)]
a.pivot(index="ORDER_ID", columns="CODE", values="STATUS_DATE").add_prefix('ACT_').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    ORDER_ID    ACT_400     ACT_500
0   19837715    22/10/19    22/10/19
1   19837833    23/10/19    23/10/19
2   19840750        NaN     23/10/19
```